# Post Id facebook share dialog always return null in Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I used test app id and log on by test user create at dash_board app on facebook develop site, require pulish_actions permission when login using login button widget of facebook sdk but result get postid always = null.
Here is my code:

```
....

shareDialog = new ShareDialog(MainActivity.this);
        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                if (result.getPostId() != null)
                    Log.e(TAG, result.getPostId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

        }
    });

    pulishButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    try{
        loginButton.setPublishPermissions(new String[]{"publish_actions","publish_stream"});
    }catch (FacebookException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.e(TAG, "success");
            loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            pulishButton.setEnabled(true);
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error
                                System.out.println("ERROR");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Success");


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }).executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e(TAG, "On cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to force ShareDialog to use Feed mode and avoid using FB's App for sharing:

```
shareDialog.show(linkContent, ShareDialog.Mode.FEED);
```

I believe this is a bug by FB. They don't send postId to onSuccess callback when using FB App for sharing (postId = null), but they do if you use Feed.

I've heard you can avoid the "postId=null" problem by using Facebook Login and demanding "publish_actions" permission. But I don't think this is the correct way to deal with this problem. Regarding the mentioned permission Facebook states:

> Publishing via dialogs or social plugins does not require this permission. Do not request review of this permission if you're only using Share dialog, Feed Dialog, Message Dialog etc, or Social Plugins (e.g. the Like Button.)

Facebook's docs on Share Dialog:

> This does not require Facebook Login or any extended permissions, so it is the easiest way to enable sharing on the web.

Comment: When using ShareDialog.Mode.FEED and SDK v4.5.0, I receive the following error: "Unable to show the provided content via the web or the installed version of the Facebook app. Some dialogs are only supported starting API 14."

Comment: when use this mode user is independent with FB app of the current device, and *they always have to login again*, it's not a good UX. yep, but I don't find out a good way for this case

Answer (score 1):

Facebook confirmed this issue in their latest update:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/478167629274681/
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/647119912303459/

Answer (score 0):

You can't login directly with "publish_action", you have to first login with any read permission then ask for for publish permissions
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#publishing

Comment: I do follow your help but still problem, here is perrmission of user facebook:
09-09 13:54:35.295  12360-12360/com.dtsgroup.facebookdemo E/MainFragment﹕ user_posts
09-09 13:54:35.295  12360-12360/com.dtsgroup.facebookdemo E/MainFragment﹕ public_profile
09-09 13:54:35.295  12360-12360/com.dtsgroup.facebookdemo E/MainFragment﹕ user_status
09-09 13:54:35.295  12360-12360/com.dtsgroup.facebookdemo E/MainFragment﹕ publish_actions


ShareResult still return postid = null

Comment: please check this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review , for any permission other than these "public_profile, user_friends and email." you have to submit your app for facebook review. If you don't want to submit now, you can create a test user in facebook developer console and try login with that. Also make sure all the details about your app in facebook dev console is correct.

Comment: Yes, i have tested by test app id and test user. I mentioned it on my question. I think i have found solution, the problem is share dialog. I just tested post status to user feed by graph api, i can get the postid. But i don't know why class Sharer.Result has method getPostId because my app has full permission required to get postID and i can't get it :(