# How to check if the user successfully done a Facebook share

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook android sdk v4.10.0 in my app and i implemented a shareDialog and works fine, What i want to do is to check if the user really shared or just clicked the back button/canceled the share process.

I have this code :

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Share success!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                UserShared();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            UserCanceled();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Also i override the onActivityResult :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

But i still can't validate that the user really shared or just canceled, on both cases the UserShared() method is invoked.

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user shared?

Answer (score -1):

[The `Sharer.Result result` has the post Id.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Sharer.Result/)

If the post id does not exist the post has been cancelled. Else your user posted.

Cheers!

Comment: This only works if the Facebook native app is not installed on the device.

Comment: What do you mean? You do not get the id of the post in the result object?If it is not null it has the id. _Helper object for handling the result from a share dialog or share operation_ from the documentation

Comment: Yes i don't get it and it always return null, Please take a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34611347/3756596)

Comment: Did you try this approach? It does seem weird.